# How to set asp.net hidden field in JavaScript and access the value in C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to set hidden field value in JS which I think works fine with this approach:

```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLatSW" runat="server" />

   var latSW = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
   $('#<%=hfLatSW.ClientID %>').value = latSW;
```

I am trying to access the value on asp.net button click in code behind gives me null value. What might be happening in the postback and why am I not able to access the value set by JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.value` isn't a jQuery property. Use `.val()`:

```
$('#<%=hfLatSW.ClientID %>').val(latSW);
```

Or without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('<%=hfLatSW.ClientID %>').value = latSW;
```